# JSON.parse without Strict Mode

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, use-strict

I'm reading the [John Resig blog](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/) about the Strict Mode in javascript, but i have a question.

One of the features of Strict Mode, is the use of JSON.parse and JSON.stringify, but i can use it WITHOUT "use strict".

If you write the same example that he's using on his blog:

```
var str = JSON.stringify({ name: "John" });
// Prints {"name":"John"}
alert( str );
```

You can see this working.

Why this is allowed? Am i missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Who says that `JSON` is only available in strict mode? It's always available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There are a number of other new features and APIs that need attention, as well. The largest of which are Strict Mode and native JSON support.

You should read this as:

> The largest of which are:
>
> - "Strict mode"
> - Native JSON support

**Not** as "JSON support, after enabling Strict mode".

See [MDN: Strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode) for more information on this topic.

Comment: Ohhhh! Sorry for the mistake! I can see it now!